# Get contacts from database

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'd like to know if there's a way to get contacts into a model so I can display a dropdown of contacts to choose from.

I can get it from "_contact_details" table, but I hope there's a better way than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data using query from _contact_details table then need link for the same where you can use, open this with ifram will better way :

```
    //slug
    $case_when = ' CASE WHEN ';
    $case_when .= $query->charLength('a.alias', '!=', '0');
    $case_when .= ' THEN ';
    $a_id = $query->castAsChar('a.id');
    $case_when .= $query->concatenate(array($a_id, 'a.alias'), ':');
    $case_when .= ' ELSE ';
    $case_when .= $a_id . ' END as slug';

    // on click redirect to the option view
<select onclick="document.location=this.value">
    <option value="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContactHelperRoute::getContactRoute($item->slug, $item->catid)); ?>&tmpl=component'">
                                <?php echo $item->name; ?></option>
</select>
```